# How to solve this equation for y?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm have found this solution to a differential equation but no initial value is given and I'm expected to solve this for y.
$$y+\frac{y^7}{7}=\frac{x^8}{8}+C$$

This was the original problem
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{x^7}{1+y^6}$$

Comment: What is your problem?

Comment: I'll add it, gimme a second

Comment: You can't explicitly write $y$ in terms of $x$ from that expression you have. Are you sure you're not just meant to find that expression and leave it at that?

Comment: It's under a group of questions that says find the explicit solution, must be a mistake. I'll talk to my teacher about it.

Comment: You can find an explicit solution for $x$. Would that be enough?

Comment: I went ahead and took that route just in case. Cheers everyone!